# Pubnub: cannot get state object with presence event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pubnub

I am trying to get data (state) object in the presence event as documented in [Pubnub Documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/tutorials/pubnub-presence).

Here's my code :-

```
// Subscribe to messages channel
Pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: $scope.channel,
    triggerEvents: ['callback','presence','message'],
    state: {
        username : $scope.username,
        membershipType : $scope.membershipType,
        memberDealsIn : $scope.memberDealsIn
    }
});

//Track online users
Pubnub.here_now({
    channel : $scope.channel,
    state: true,
    callback : function(m){
        $scope.$apply(function() {

            $scope.onlineUsers.push(m['uuids'])
        });
    }
});

//User's State
Pubnub.state({
    channel  : $scope.channel,
    state    : {
        username : $scope.username,
        membershipType : $scope.membershipType,
        memberDealsIn : $scope.memberDealsIn
    },
    callback : function(m){
        //console.log(m)
    },
    error    : function(m){
        //console.log(m)
    }
});
```

I am calling it from the Pubnub's getPresenceEventNameFor method as :-

```
$scope.$on(Pubnub.getPresenceEventNameFor($scope.channel), function (ngEvent, pnEvent) {
   console.log("pnEvent: ", pnEvent);
}
```

Here's my output :-

```
pnEvent:  Object {action: "join", uuid: "1310974", timestamp: 1467719168, occupancy: 3}
```

As you can see everything else is just fine but I cannot get data in it.
Whereas the [Documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angularjs-javascript/presence) says it should have data too, like :-

```
{
"action" : "join",
"timestamp" : 1345546797,
"uuid" : "175c2c67-b2a9-470d-8f4b-1db94f90e39e",
"occupancy" : 2,
"data" : {
    "age" : 67,
    "full" : "RobertPlant",
    "country" : "UK",
    "appstate" : "foreground",
    "latlong" : "51.5072°N,0.1275°W"
    }
}
```

I have been stuck with this thing for a while now. :(

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here. Why isn't the state being set in the presence event.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should not subscribe with state because it does not always yield expected results in all cases. Instead, best practice is to subscribe and then when the client get's its own join event, set state. Then you will get the state-change event in a reliable, consistent fashion. Let me know if this addresses you issue. If it doesn't, then probably best to submit email to [PubNub Support](http://pubnub.com/support) with details and link to this thread so we can post back with final solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by   **" when the client get's its own join event, set state".**  I am setting the state when here_now event is triggered. First time I am generating the online users list by here_now event. And I need state in presence event too because I am re-generating the online users list by presence event. Where am I supposed to get data (state) from if a user has just come online? I think I can detect new users from presence event only right? So data needs to be in presence event.

Comment: Provided details in the support ticket. Will post back here when we have reached a good solution for you.

Comment: I have the same problem now.  Have you found a solution to this by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. I have been able to detect the issue, thanks to pubnub support.
It was due to the wrong timing of events.
In my code, the here_now event was being triggered before the presence event for the user where its state is being set.

Now I am setting the state in the user's own join event and calling the here_now event in the state-change event. And its working.

```
    //Presence Callback
$scope.$on(Pubnub.getPresenceEventNameFor($scope.channel), function (ngEvent, pnEvent, envelope, channel) {

    //Detect Join events for users
    if (pnEvent['action'] === 'join') {

        //Detect User's own join event and set state for the user
        if (pnEvent['uuid'] === $scope.uuid) {
            //User's State
            Pubnub.state({
                channel  : $scope.channel,
                state    : {
                    username : $scope.username,
                    membershipType : $scope.membershipType,
                    memberDealsIn : $scope.memberDealsIn
                },
                callback : function(m){
                    //console.log(m)
                },
                error    : function(m){
                    //console.log(m)
                }
            });   
        }
    }

    //Detect state change event
    if (pnEvent['action'] === 'state-change') {

        //Call here_now on state change of a user
        //Track online users
        Pubnub.here_now({
            channel : $scope.channel,
            state: true,
            callback : function(m){
                $scope.$apply(function() {

                    for (var userIdx in m['uuids']) {
                        var user = m['uuids'][userIdx];

                        //Push new user to online User's list if not there
                        if (!_.find($scope.onlineUsers, {uuid: user.uuid}) && (user.uuid != $scope.uuid)){

                            //Push only if state is not undefined
                            if (user.state.membershipType != null) {
                                $scope.onlineUsers.push({uuid: user.uuid, membership: user.state.membershipType, dealsin: user.state.memberDealsIn, username: user.state.username});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```